# sendmail threshold questions in ubuntu on aws ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sendmail

I have sendmail (I know, not postfix, but it's what I've got) up and running on an ubuntu ec2 instance on aws.  Everything is working but I have a couple of questions on whether or not the following are configurable options (and how/where to configure):

As a practical example, I have a php script in my crontab that runs once a week and sends an email to 140+ users.  When I run `mailq` or `sendmail -v -q` I can see that all of the emails are queued up.  It seems that the emails are only sent out 1 per 3 minutes, though.

Now for the questions:

1. Is it possible to have sendmail "blast" out the emails to all unique recipients without waiting 3 minutes between?
2. Is it possible to adjust the 3 minute wait time between emails to the same recipient? (Some admin users receive more than one email with different reports).

I've poked around in `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` but couldn't figure out what setting to tweak (or if I was even looking in the right place).

Thank you all in advance for the assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon limits outbound mail from EC2s. [From their FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances):

> Q: Are there any limitations in sending email from EC2 instances?
>
> A: Yes.[...] we enforce default limits on the amount of email that can
>   be sent

They have a form where you can ask for your limit to be increased, but that isn't the correct way to do it- the correct way is to use [Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/). You can access it with a SMTP endpoint, so it should be fairly trivial to implement.

AWS even has documentation to assist you: "[Integrating Amazon SES with Sendmail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html)".

Comment: We had ours upped to 25,000 a day and 10/second. Just put a request in and then make sure you add a wait to the script so it doesn't get throttled. we use a combination of SES .NET SDK and SMTP and send around 1,000-3,000 a day